# exclude unwanted text in multiple lines that came up by parsing html with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
years = list(range(1956,2016))


for year in years:
    my_urls = ('http://www.hitparadeitalia.it/hp_yends/hpe' + str(year) + '.htm',)
    my_url = my_urls[0]
    for my_url in my_urls:
        uClient = uReq(my_url)
        html_input = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_input, "html.parser")
        container = page_soup.findAll("li")
        filename = "singoli" + str(year) + ".csv"
        f = open(filename, "w")
        headers = "lista"
        f.write(headers)
        lista = container[0].text
        print("lista: " + lista)
        f.write(lista + "\n")
        f.close()
```

I get text that does not seem to be in the "li" container but it gets written in the outputs. This is the unwanted text:

```
<!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-9635531430093553";
/* in medias res */
google_ad_slot = "9880694813";
google_ad_width = 468;
google_ad_height = 60;
//-->
```

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text you don't want is coming from a script element. So get rid of the script elements before you start and it works:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
years = list(range(1956,2016))


for year in years:
    my_urls = ('http://www.hitparadeitalia.it/hp_yends/hpe' + str(year) + '.htm',)
    my_url = my_urls[0]
    for my_url in my_urls:
        uClient = uReq(my_url)
        html_input = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_input, "html.parser")
        [s.extract() for s in page_soup('script')]
        container = page_soup.findAll("li")
        filename = "singoli" + str(year) + ".csv"
        f = open(filename, "w")
        headers = "lista"
        f.write(headers)
        lista = container[0].text
        print("lista: " + lista)
        f.write(lista + "\n")
        f.close()
```

All I did was to add the one line:

```
[s.extract() for s in page_soup('script')]
```

Which finds the script elements and removes them.